# Convert or transform the list

Tags: r

Input list is:

```
  $A
[1] 25

  $B
[1] 22

  $C
 [1] 25

 $D
 [1] 26
 ----
```

Need to convert this to

```
$25
[1] "A" "C"

$22
[1] "B"

$26
[1] "D"
```

---

How do I change the grouping?  Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `list` is called "L" (example below), try:

```
L <- list(A = 25, B = 22, C = 25, D = 26)
split(names(L), unlist(L))
# $`22`
# [1] "B"
# 
# $`25`
# [1] "A" "C"
# 
# $`26`
# [1] "D"
```

You could also try `with(stack(L), split(as.character(ind), values))`.

Comment: Very nice.  I struggled a bit with this one.